# Как сделать так чтобы бот выносил функцию обработки в отдельный поток и не стопил при этом всего бота Aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, multiprocessing

```py
def work_with_img(image, var):
    image = np.array(image/255, dtype=float)
    noise = np.random.normal(0, var ** 0.5, image.shape)
    out = image + noise
    out = np.clip(out, 0, 1.0)
    out = np.uint8(out*255)
    return out

def per(img):
    img1=cv2.imread(img)#путь до изображения
    e=gen(random.randint(12,20))
    u=work_with_img(img1,0.0003)
    cv2.imwrite(f'{e}.jpg',u)
    return f"{e}.jpg"#обработка изображений

@dp.callback_query_handler(state='ph')
async def  ph_work(call: types.CallbackQuery,state: FSMContext):
            async with state.proxy() as data:
                    src: src = data.get("info")
            await bot.delete_message(chat_id=call.from_user.id, message_id=call.message.message_id)
            await call.message.answer(f'{tim}Обработка начата{tim}')
            media = types.MediaGroup()
            for i in range(5):
                media.attach_document(types.InputFile(per(src)))
            await call.message.answer_media_group(media=media)
            await state.finish()
            os.remove(src)
```

Comment: Как минимум было бы круто увидеть код

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но если используете асинхронный бот, то и все методы и библиотеки, что будете использовать тоже должны быть асинхронными

Comment: @gil9red если эта функция не жрет слишком много времени то это не важно

Comment: @oleksandrigo в том то и дело что жрет, а пока жрет ещё и на остальных юзеров не реагирует

Comment: @gil9red подскажи как сделать функцию work_with_img асинхронной

Comment: @fors, мне сложно тут помочь именно по этой теме, но я попробую... async хорош там, где есть работа по сети, с базой данных, файлами, но не с CPU (и, думаю, с GPU), а numpy наверняка только с CPU работает. Возможно, лучше создать поток или пулпотоков и им отправлять обработку картинки и ждать пока они обработают и можно забрать результат. Лично у меня боты были на python-telegram-bot (~13 версии) и там используются потоки для обработки каждого запроса: https://github.com/gil9red/telegram_bot__image_process_bot/blob/745d696c5f62e6e4552c51127a3261c36d4a9dc7/main.py#L157

Comment: с вопросом разобрался так, обработку файлов вынес в отдельный поток сложность возникла с тем как внутри синхронного потока отправлять сообщения(aiogram библиотека aсинхронная) получилось отправлять и сообщения и медиагруппы с помощью past запросов